# How to redirect in IIS7 for this url format

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

I wonder how to do specific redirection based on the scenario below?

When people open this url at browser `http://www.test.com/gotogoogle` it will redirect them to `http://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with URL Rewrite module. The rule will be (content of **web.config** from website root folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Go To Google" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^gotogoogle$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you already have web,config, then add appropriate fragment only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RewriteMap in the IIS7 URL Rewrite module to achieve this..

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/